# Python: Decorators: How does the following code work?

Tags: python, decorator

**Are the comments in the following code correct? Particularly the "instance =..." one?**

```
# This does nothing.

class donothing(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        """
        The 'func' argument is the function being decorated because in this
        case, we're not instantiating the decorator class. Instead we are just
        using the class object as a callable (a class is always callable as this
        is how an instance is returned) to use as a decorator, which means that
        it is being instantiated upon definition of the decorated function and
        the decorated function is being passed in as an argument to the class's
        __init__ method.
        """
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        The __call__ function is called when the decorated function is called
        because the function has be eaten by the decorator class. Now it's up to
        the this method to return a call to the original function. The arguments
        are passed in as args, kwargs to be manipulated.
        """
        # Returns original function call with original arguments.
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

@donothing
def printer(text):
    print(text)

printer('hello world')

# The printer function is now an alias for the donothing instance created, so
# the preceding was the same as:
#
# instance = donothing(printer)
# instance('hello world')
#


# Next example:

class checkforkeysinparams(object):
    def __init__(self, required):
        self.required = set(required)

    def __call__(self, params):
        def wrapper(params):
            missing = self.required.difference(params)
            if missing:
                raise TypeError('Missing from "params" argument: %s' % ', '.join(sorted(missing)))
        return wrapper


# Apply decorator class, passing in the __init__'s 'required' argument.

@checkforkeysinparams(['name', 'pass', 'code'])
def complex_function(params):
    # Obviously these three are needed or a KeyError will be raised.
    print(params['name'])
    print(params['pass'])
    print(params['code'])


# Create params to pass in. Note, I've commented out one of the required params.

params = {
    'name': 'John Doe',
    'pass': 'OpenSesame',
    #'code': '1134',
}

# This call will output: TypeError: Missing from "params" argument: code

complex_function(params=params)
```

Comment: Yes, the `instance = ...` stuff is pretty much how the `@donothing` decorator gets used, internally.

Comment: You could just test it instead of asking "does this work?"...

Comment: @Tor Valamo Learn to read sometime. It's very liberating. My question was: "How does the following code work?"

Comment: Amusingly, what you call `donothing` is actually quite similar to how the builtin `staticmethod` functions in practice (though not in implementation). In fact I recently had a situation in which `staticmethod` wasn't quite working the way I needed it to, so I came up with your exact class, except I actually called it `staticmethod` and I've been using it as a drop-in replacement for staticmethods that is slightly more flexible than the real thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes perfect description, decorator `donothing` decorates the function `printer` and returns a object of class `donothing`, so yes decorator simply boils down to this

```
x = donothing(func) # donothing is a class not function
```

and you can use it like this, if you wish to avoid @deco syntax.

so now x is an object, when you do x(), `__call__` of that object is called and there it calls the function which was passed in `__init__`

**edit:**
Second decorator is wrong , because it only checks the parameter but never calls the function being passed
and function being passed to decorator is names `params` but should be name something like func or better name

you can test that it does nothing by passing correct params

```
params = {
    'name': 'John Doe',
    'pass': 'OpenSesame',
    'code': '1134',
}
complex_function(params=params)
```

it doesn't print the arguments as complex_function is supposed to do.

so correct decorator is

```
class checkforkeysinparams(object):
    def __init__(self, required):
        self.required = set(required)

    def __call__(self, func):
        def wrapper(params):
            missing = self.required.difference(params)
            if missing:
                raise TypeError('Missing from "params" argument: %s' % ', '.join(sorted(missing)))

            func(params)

        return wrapper
```

In first example Class is being used as decorator itself, here the object of class `checkforkeysinparams` is used as deocrator
hence function gets passed to `__call__` of that object

Comment: Sweet thx for clarifying, BTW, I love the @ syntax. And what about the second one.

Comment: @orokusaki, I added explanation of second decorator, which btw is wrongly coded